# Using grep to compare two lists of Python packages

Tags: python, bash, list, shell, grep

I want to generate the list of packages install in Python 3, the list of all packages in Python 2.7 and find all entries in the 2.7 list *not* in the Python 3 list.

Generating the list is easy: `pip freeze` or `pip3.4 freeze`.

Searching for a package in the list is equally trivial `pip freeze | grep "wheel"` for example

However, if I want to search for intersections between the list, or in this instance *non*-intersections I would expect to use something like this `pip freeze | grep -n pip3.4 freeze`

However it tells me that, obviously the parameter for grep `...is not a file or directory`. My shell scripting is rusty and I vaguely remember there should be a simple way of doing this other than piping both lists to files?

Comment: `grep -vf <(pip freeze) <(pip3.4 freeze)`

Comment: @123 To list all python2 packages not in python3 list I think it should be `grep -vf <(pip3.4 freeze) <(pip freeze)`

Comment: @Kenavoz yeah, tbh i didn't really read the question, just saw `I want to search for intersections between the list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use also comm command as below

```
comm -12 <(pip freeze) <(pip3.4 freeze)
```

to search for intersections;

```
grep -f <(pip freeze) <(pip3.4 freeze)
```

Comment: This only works if the installed package versions match, and the second example treats a `.` in package names or versions as wildcard. Something like `grep -F -x -f <(pip2 freeze | sed 's/==.*//') <(pip3 freeze | sed 's/==.*//')` would ignore version numbers and match for full strings only.